# How do I install Gradle into the Android folder of an application?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

I am working on an application which uses Cordova to establish a Bluetooth connection between an Android phone and an Arduino. I am using the [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) library in my application.

Whenever I execute `cordova build android`, it throws an error saying that it cannot find Gradle in my  Android SDK installation. In an attempt to solve this, I installed Gradle through Homebrew, but Cordova did not find it.

```
WT0892:counter iosdev$ cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/iosdev/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /Users/iosdev/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

How can I install Gradle into my Android SDK? If that's not the right way to fix this problem, how can I tell Cordova where to find Gradle?